# how to remove the comma after the number 19

Tags: java, arrays

How do I remove the comma after the number 19?

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbers[] = {23, 79, 41, 68, 17, 39, 51, 75, 95, 19};
    System.out.print("Integer values: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
      System.out.print(numbers[i] + ",");
      

    }
    int smallestNumber = numbers[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
      if (numbers[i] < smallestNumber){
        smallestNumber = numbers[i];
      }  
  }
    System.out.println("\nSmallest integer: " + smallestNumber);

}
}
```

This is how it looks like after its run

```
Integer values: 23,79,41,68,17,39,51,75,95,19,
Smallest integer: 17
```

This is how I want it to look

```
Integer values: 23,79,41,68,17,39,51,75,95,19
Smallest integer: 17
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString` instead of a custom loop. Or add an `if` to check for last element

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
  System.out.print(numbers[i] + ",");
}
System.out.print(numbers[numbers.length - 1]);
```

Or use streams

```
 Arrays.stream(numbers).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

**StringJoiner** is used to construct a sequence of characters separated by a delimiter and optionally starting with a supplied prefix and ending with a supplied suffix. Here in this case we are using the delimiter as `,`

```
int numbers[] = {23, 79, 41, 68, 17, 39, 51, 75, 95, 19};
StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");

System.out.print("Integer values: ");
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   stringJoiner.add(String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
}

System.out.println(stringJoiner);
```

Comment: From the [docs of StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) : "A StringJoiner may be employed to create formatted output from a Stream using Collectors.joining"

Answer (score 0):

*Just to add-on:*

***You can also use `streams` to find the minimum integer from the given array:***

```
int numbers[] = {23, 79, 41, 68, 17, 39, 51, 75, 95, 19};
        Optional<Integer> minNumber = Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed()
                                     .min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        minNumber.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
17
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is hard coded, you know the array will never be size 0.  You can print the first element.  Then have a loop that prints the rest of the elements each with a comma prepended.

```
    int numbers[] = {23, 79, 41, 68, 17, 39, 51, 75, 95, 19};
    
    System.out.print("Integer values: ");
    System.out.print(numbers[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
      System.out.print("," + numbers[i]);
    }
```